# what is the correct mapping in JAVA for a Varchar DB column which holds numeric values?

Tags: java, excel, hibernate, postgresql

I have a column defined in a table in postgres DB as:

```
counterparty_company_number character varying(255)
```

I have written a JAVA code to populate this table with values from corresponding columns of an excel file. In the sample excel file, this column has 8 rows,out of which some are blank,like:

counterparty_company_number

```
blank
234567
345678
456789
567890
1.03E+09
blank
blank
```

In my model class,I have defined the attribute for this column as:

```
private String counterparty_company_number;
```

In my code, I replaced blank values with empty String while saving.After reading the data from excel and saving in DB,the values in corresponding column of DB table appear as:

```
""
"234567.0"
"345678.0"
"456789.0"
"567890.0"
"1.0304388E9"
""
""
```

This is the snippet from the code that reads the excel file and populates the table in DB:

```
..
//reads excel file and stores values in a list
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(filepath));
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
XSSFSheet xssfSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
if (xssfSheet.getLastRowNum() != 0) {
for (int i = 1; i <= xssfSheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
Row row = xssfSheet.getRow(i);
for (int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
if (cell != null) {
valueHolder.add(cell.toString());
} else {valueHolder.add("");
}
}
}
}
..
//sets attribute values in model class
if (!valueHolder.isEmpty() && valueHolder != null) {
for (int i = 0; i < valueHolder.size(); i += 10) {
CardsCounterparty ccp = new CardsCounterparty();
..
ccp.setCounterparty_company_number(valueHolder.get(i+3).toString());
..
counterpartyList.add(ccp);//counterpartyList is a list of counterparty objects
}
}
return counterpartyList;//this list is passed to the code that will save the objects in    DB table
}
..
//code to persist in DB 
Configuration c = new Configuration();
c.configure("/hibernate.cfg.xml");
SessionFactory sf = c.buildSessionFactory();
Session s = sf.openSession();
Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
try {
for (int i = 0; i < counterparties.size(); i++) {//counterparties is the list of all counterparty objects to be saved
CardsCounterparty ccp = counterparties.get(i);
s.save(ccp);
}
tx.commit();
s.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
tx.rollback();
}
}
```

I want to know how can I get the values in proper numeric format like **234567** instead of **234567.0** and **1030438800** instead of **1.0304388E9**. I cannot change the datatype to **int** from **String** as the values may contain characters also and there may be blank values also.

Comment: just treat it always as a string

Comment: @I wish I could think of a good: I am treating it as string only.But then the value gets saved as decimal value in DB.

Comment: The correct mapping for a varchar column containing numeric data is *not to use varchar for numbers in the first place*. If it's a number, use a numeric data type (integer, float8, numeric, etc) in the database.

Comment: @CraigRinger The DB is designed by other team,so i cannot change that.

Comment: Dark alley, baseball bat, ...

Comment: @CraigRinger Usually I would agree but, if the number is not being treated as a number with no arithmetic (phone number, ssn number, company number etc) then I would store as varchar

Answer (score 0):

Examine your SQL to ensure that the value that is getting inserted is surrounded by quotes to prevent any conversion from happening.

```
"update tablex set counterparty_company_number = '" + value + "'"
```

Comment: Yes,the values are coming surrounded with quotes.